# How can I convert wavrecord to audiorecorder?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a code that no longer works in recent versions of matlab because wavrecord is no longer used. How can I convert this:

```
Fs=8000;

my_voice=wavrecord(3*Fs,Fs,'int16');

wavplay(myvoice,Fs);
```

in a way that works on Matlab now?

Comment: Check out https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/165279-how-to-change-wavrecord-to-audiorecorder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Code:**

```
% Setup the recording object
Fs = 8000;
Nbits = 16;
my_recorder = audiorecorder(Fs, Nbits, 1)

% Record the audio
record(my_recorder, 3);
% Retrieve the sampled recording
my_voice = getaudiodata(my_recorder);
% Play the sampled recording
play(my_voice);
```

This will reproduce the code you've posted in your question (similar to the [answer @Jørgen linked in the comments](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/165279-how-to-change-wavrecord-to-audiorecorder#answer_161158)).

**Explanation of the Above Code:**

First, let's break down what your code did.

[`my_voice = wavrecord(3*Fs, Fs, 'int16')`](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/techdoc/ref/wavrecord.html) records `3` seconds of 16-bit audio sampled at `Fs = 8000` Hz. When you do not specify a channel the default is `mono`, or 1-channel input.

Now, you want to replicate this behavior with the `audiorecorder()` function.

[`audiorecorder(Fs, nBits, nChannels)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiorecorder.html) creates an `audiorecorder` object that samples `nBits` audio at `Fs` Hz.

You want to record 16-bit audio, so `nBits = 16` sampled at `Fs = 8000` Hz and since you did not specify a channel with `wavrecord()` you were using 1-channel audio input, so `nChannels` here is `1`: `my_recorder = audiorecorder(8000,16,1)`.

You still want to specify a recording time of `3` seconds. So, you should record data from the `my_recorder` object for `3` seconds: `record(my_recorder, 3)`.

In order to retrieve the sampled audio: `my_voice = getaudiodata(my_recorder)`.